# How to get FK table data when querying PK table in .Net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a primary key `spe_manuscript_num` in table `SPE_COMMON_DATA` and it is FK to other tables:

[image]

But the .NET Core model is generated by `Scaffold-DbContext` like this:

```
public partial class SpeCommonData
{     
    public string SpeManuscriptNum { get; set; }
    ..
    ..
    public virtual ICollection<SpeAttachment> SpeAttachment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SpeMiscData> SpeMiscData { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       modelBuilder.Entity<SpeCommonData>(entity =>
        {
               ....
               //nothing about FK tables
        }
        modelBuilder.Entity<SpeMiscData>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("SPE_MISC_DATA");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .HasColumnType("numeric(38, 0)")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.SpeManuscriptNum)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("spe_manuscript_num")
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .IsUnicode(false);
             ....
            entity.HasOne(d => d.SpeManuscriptNumNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.SpeMiscData)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SpeManuscriptNum)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__SPE_MISC___spe_m__02084FDA");
        });
     modelBuilder.Entity<SpeAttachment>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.AttachmentId)
                .HasName("PK__SPE_ATTA__B74DF4E2D1989600");

            entity.ToTable("SPE_ATTACHMENT");

            entity.Property(e => e.AttachmentId).HasColumnName("attachment_id");
            ...
            entity.Property(e => e.SpeManuscriptNum)
                .HasColumnName("spe_manuscript_num")
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.SpeManuscriptNumNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.SpeAttachment)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SpeManuscriptNum)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__SPE_ATTAC__spe_m__3EA749C6");
        });
```

My question is when I query table `SPE_COMMON_DATA` I am not able to pull other tables data based on `FK` I know nothing defined in `modelBuilder.Entity<SpeCommonData>`?

How to get other tables data also when query `SPE_COMMON_DATA`, like the ORM model?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity should have reference to the entities that have FK relations. Then while querying you can use Include method of EF so that it queries and returns FK tables as well.

Can you check this link please learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data